# How to solve no space left on device when running hive query on aws emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, emr

I have aws emr setup with me on which I run my hive queries.
As of now the hardware setup is as follows.

One Master - m3.xlarge
8 vCPU, 15 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none

Fifteen Core Node - m3.xlarge
8 vCPU, 15 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none

My query deal with around 500 million record and they become part of internal hive table.
I perform merge query on these internal table.

Now i know one solution where if I increase the number of core nodes, the problem will be gone.
But I need help in understanding why this error actually happened and how to debug and solve it. I there any reference material to refer to.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
For Reason - org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1507712059631_0734_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1507712059631_0734_1_01_000066, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_1507712059631_0734_01_000056 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=-100. Container released on a *lost* node]], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Container container_1507712059631_0734_01_000038 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=-100. Container released on a *lost* node]], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Encountered an FSError while executing task: attempt_1507712059631_0734_1_01_000066_2:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:253)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:60)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.IFileOutputStream.write(IFileOutputStream.java:120)
at
```

Comment: Did you find solution ? I have same problem m4.2xlarge InstanceCount=20 I am  doing load with sparkSQL and it still throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

Hive with MapReduce engine stores intermediate results on disk. If the intermediate result size exceeds the availabe disk space (which can easily happen during join operations), well, this results in an error.

You can try SparkSql instead, which optimizes your query before executing in. The hive commands can be just re-used.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/

As a frontend you could use zeppelin or jupyter notebooks, or you write some small spark job in java or scala.